# JQuery plugin hiding buttons

Tags: .net, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have buttons on the side of my page created like this:

```
<div id="actions" style="display: none">
                        <div style="text-align: left; cursor: pointer;" id="openTemplateDialogButton">
                            <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/btn_user_save_template_off.gif")%>" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: left; cursor: pointer;" id="saveButton">
                            <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/btn_user_save_lg_off.gif")%>" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="saveButtonMessage" style="font-style: italic">
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div id="calculateButton" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/btn_calculate.gif")%>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I want to encapsuate them in a JQuery "bubble" that we used throughout the rest of our app fine. Now, without the bubble, the buttons display fine, with the bubble, the buttons are "covered" I think? And you can't see them. here is the bubble code:

```
$("#actions").bubble({ width: 50, title:'Actions'});
```

This bubble works fine in all other parts of the app so I know it's not the bubble code, just somehow how it works together.

Any ideas?

---

Comment: it really depends what bubble does, by the sounds of it bubble only wraps one level, so by wrapping the actions div you are not wrapping the inner divs as bubbles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a work around. I just "bubbled" each image within the main Div and did it that way.